Name for a minor chord progression using primarilyy Am G F E (with D or Dm and C sometimes)
The "Walk Don't Run" chord progression goes Am G F E. Then has a bridge in C major.
Am is the relative minor of C, so the verse is in A minor.
 became the three chords on which metal songs were built. (Stairway to Heaven). You can hear the progression in music from the 1500's. Are there general and academic names for this tonality?

It's generally known as the Spanish sequence, or the Andalusian cadence, which keeps on repeating, as it reaches the V of the key.
